# Calculate Expectation of Waiting Time at Traffic Signals

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

So I came across this elementary problem but am not sure whether I am doing it right. Need community help.

Question: At a Traffic Signal, Red light is on for $30$ seconds, Green Light is on for $30$ seconds. I need to find the Expected waiting time at Traffic Signal. I am not sure whether my answer/approach is correct or not as I do not know the answer to question.

Please check whether my Approach is correct or not:

---

Random Variable $X = [0,30] \ $ (Waiting time at signal) - Continuous Random Variable

---

$P[X=0] = \frac 12$

---

$P[0 \lt x \le 30] = \frac{1}{60} \cdot  30$, follows Uniform Distribution

[image]

> P.S: I am sorry it might seem a straightforward question to the
> community, but I am just a beginner in applied prob. and stats.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you integrating from $1$ to $30$ rather than from $0$ to $30$?

Comment: My mistake, it should be from 0 to 30, I have corrected it. Is my answer correct? @Henry

Comment: You should learn basic mathjax to type your math. It is not encouraged to add your question or your attempt as an image. Here is a basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your answer is correct. You can simply do this too -

The probability that you get a green light is $\frac{1}{2}$ and it is the same that you get a red light.

If the light is green, the expected wait time is $0$. If the light is red, the average wait time is $15$ seconds.

So the expected wait time is

$ \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 15 = 7.5$ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could arrive at one of 60 seconds, with 30 of them yielding no wait (green light) and 30 yielding some wait (red light). So the probability of a $30$ second wait is $1/60$, and same for a $29$ second wait, $28$, and so on.

So in total, the expected wait is $(1/60)(30 + 29 + 28+\dots)$. So just integrate $f(x)=x$ from $0$ to $30$, and divide that by 60 and you have your expected wait time, which does come out to $7.5$, so good job.

Edit: These are just my informal thoughts as someone without really any expertise so grain of salt.